# DLLImport PInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to wrap the bass.dll. Simple functions not too Advanced. Dont want to get that deep. However i am facing problems.
This is how i import the functions:

```
        [DllImport("bass.dll")]
        public static extern long BASS_Start();
        [DllImport("bass.dll")]
        public static extern bool BASS_Init(int device, uint freq, uint flag, IntPtr hParent, uint GUID);
        [DllImport("bass.dll")]
        public static extern long BASS_StreamCreateFile(bool mem, string file, uint offset, uint length, uint flags);
        [DllImport("bass.dll")]
        public static extern long BASS_ChannelPlay(long handle, long restart);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

but when i call them, it doesn't work. I get the PInvokeStackImbalance error.

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\testv.1.0.0\update\updated\test\test\bin\Release\test.exe'.

Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'test!test.Main::BASS_StreamCreateFile' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
```

This is the way i am calling them.

```
        BASS_Start();
        BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        long handle = BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\James Morrison.mp3", 0, 0, 0);
        //MessageBox.Show("Playing: " + handle.ToString());
        BASS_ChannelPlay(handle, 1);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

I tried desactivating PInvokeStackImbalance but it didn't change anything. Just stopped occuring PInvokeStackImbalance. Hence it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. please don't give me advices to use Bass.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translations are very badly wrong. Every single one contains mistakes, I am afraid to say.

They should be:

```
[DllImport("bass.dll")]
public static extern bool BASS_Start();

[DllImport("bass.dll")]
public static extern bool BASS_Init(int device, uint freq, uint flag, 
     IntPtr hParent, ref GUID guid);

[DllImport("bass.dll")]
public static extern uint BASS_StreamCreateFile(bool mem, string file, ulong offset, 
    ulong length, uint flags);

[DllImport("bass.dll")]
public static extern bool BASS_ChannelPlay(uint handle, bool restart);
```

I suggest that you make sure you have the BASS C++ header file at hand, and also that you revise your knowledge of what the basic types are for C++ and C#.

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but i don't have the BASS C++ header file at hand.
However what you suggested wasn't correct. I found the answer though. I will post it

Comment: Yes. You are wrong. Without the header file you won't get anywhere.

Comment: Yeap my bad. Mine works but i think you solution is the correct one.
If you can feed me the header file i would much appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: I found it with a websearch. You can get it from the bass website. You really need to get that sdk.

Comment: Found it. Thank you for the support David. Cheers.